# Hash of a String object is 0

Tags: java, xml, string, hash

Scenario: There is a message sender and a message receiver. The contents of the message are converted into a xom.nu document and passed to the receiver. Something funny happens here.
There is an attribute (language) for one of the tags, i.e text, whose value is a string "en".

The sender's "en" has a hash value but the receiver's hash is shown to be zero. What causes the hash of a string be zero?

Sender:

[image: Sender Image]

Receiver:

[image: Receiver Image]

Comment: That means `hash` not yet calculated ??

Comment: Suresh is right I think, try calling `hashCode()`. Also, hashCode on different platforms is not guaranteed to be the same.

Comment: @Marcelo The hash algorithm is defined in the documentation. So it's platform independent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should not inspect a variable only by its internals.

In this case your problem is that the field `hash` is acting as a *cache*. It only contains a value if `hashCode()` has ever been called on *this instance*.

Try watching `yourVariable.hashCode()` and you'll notice that the `hash` field will change as well.

Answer (score 7):

Here's the source of the `hashCode` method :

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0) {
        int off = offset;
        char val[] = value;
        int len = count;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            h = 31*h + val[off++];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

You see that the value is computed only when you (first) call `hashCode`. Which doesn't matter as `hash` **is private** : you can only get it normally using the `hashCode` method.

To answer your explicit question : the hash of a string (as returned by `hashCode`) is `0` for empty strings (but [not only for empty strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746394/can-a-not-empty-string-have-a-hashcode-of-zero)).

Comment: The hashCode() value is not only zero for empty strings.