# Can a non-empty string have a hashcode of zero?

Tags: java, string, hash, integer-overflow

By "non-empty", I mean in this question a string which contains at least one non-zero character.

For reference, here's the `hashCode` implementation :

```
1493    public int hashCode() {
1494        int h = hash;
1495        if (h == 0) {
1496            int off = offset;
1497            char val[] = value;
1498            int len = count;
1499
1500            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
1501                h = 31*h + val[off++];
1502            }
1503            hash = h;
1504        }
1505        return h;
1506    }
```

and the algorithm is specified in the documentation.

Before an integer overflow occurs, the answer is easy: it's no. But what I'd like to know is if, due to integer overflow, it's possible for a non-empty string to have a hashcode of zero? Can you construct one?

What I'm looking for would ideally be a mathematical demonstration (or a link to one) or a construction algorithm.

Comment: What do you mean by *null hashcode*? The type is `int`?

Comment: @RohitJain Damn, my English fails me (in French "nul" means "zero"). Edited.

Comment: also not sure what "long" you're referring to.  hashCode() method deals in ints and chars.

Comment: I guess it might be possible. but finding an exact case will be a headache.

Comment: Yes it's possible but highly unlikely.

Comment: its perfectly valid to have a hash code as zero since it does not violate any of the rules of hash code

Comment: @ankit The String class has an additional specification (see javadoc).

Comment: How can this question be "too broad" ?

Comment: @dystroy the question has changed significantly since you asked it, and now you're looking for a mathematical demonstration.

Comment: @JoopEggen Please read the question until the first sentence...

Comment: This reminds me of when some Google employees tried to find a `String` that had `Integer.MIN_VALUE` as its hashcode for some Java puzzle.

Comment: Why do you care? Your code should never be assuming that hash collisions are impossible.

Comment: @Raedwald To begin with I was curious of the assumption behind the hash cache implementation. And next, I was curious. I didn't learn to code by not being curious.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Sure. The string **f5a5a608** for example has a hashcode of zero.

I found that through a simple brute force search:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    long i = 0;
    loop: while(true){
        String s = Long.toHexString(i);
        if(s.hashCode() == 0){
            System.out.println("Found: '"+s+"'");
            break loop;
        }
        if(i % 1000000==0){
            System.out.println("checked: "+i);              
        }
        i++;
    }       
}
```

**Edit:** Joseph Darcy, who worked on the JVM, even wrote a program that can [construct a string with a given hashcode](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/string_unhashing) (to test the implementation of Strings in switch/case statements) by basically running the hash algorithm in reverse.

Comment: `Incentively, my dear, I don't tessellate a derangement.` Hashcodes to zero. There are a lot of them. Think of it this way, you have roughly a 2^-64 chance a String will hash to zero. Then think of how many possible Strings there are.

Comment: @Obicere I wasn't at all sure that the overflows were able to lead to a zero value.

Comment: @Obicere: It's not necessarily true that a hash function will use all hash values with equal likelihood (or at all), though of course you'd expect that from a *good* hash function.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Of course, but the more characters the better the distribution. When approaching infinite characters, it should approach that value. Also, with the more characters, the less significance the 1-or-2 character strings impact the results, due to the exponential gain of string permutations.

Comment: I don't think the unhash function can work for this purpose. It would only find the string made of zero chars.

Comment: @Obicere: I was thinking about a skewed hash function, not the input. Oh, and the hashcode is an int, so it's a 1  in 2^32 chance. Otherwise, my brute force approach would have been rather futile.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt ah yes, thanks for correcting that. No idea why I thought it was 64 haha

Answer (score 2):

just be care of that `int h;`. It may overflow, every string that satisfy `h % 2^31 == 0` may lead to this.

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String []args) {
       System.out.println("\u0001!qbygvW".hashCode());
        System.out.println("9 $Ql(0".hashCode());
        System.out.println(" #t(}lrl".hashCode());
        System.out.println(" !!#jbw}a".hashCode());
        System.out.println(" !!#jbw|||".hashCode());
        System.out.println(" !!!!Se|aaJ".hashCode());
        System.out.println(" !!!!\"xurlls".hashCode());
    }
}
```

A lot of strings...

Answer (score 1):

Here's code to find and print strings of any desired `hashCode` value:

```
public static int findIntInverse(int x) {
    // find the number y such that as an int (after overflow) x*y = 1
    // assumes x is odd, because without that it isn't possible.
    // works by computing x ** ((2 ** 32) - 1)
    int retval = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
        retval *= retval;
        retval *= x;
    }
    return retval;
}

public static void findStrings(
        int targetHash,
        Iterable<String> firstParts,
        Iterable<String> midParts,
        Iterable<String> lastParts) {
    Map<Integer, String> firstHashes = new HashMap<>();
    for (String firstPart : firstParts) {
        firstHashes.put(firstPart.hashCode(), firstPart);
    }
    int maxlastlen = 0;
    int maxmidlen = 0;
    for (String midPart : midParts) {
        maxmidlen = Math.max(midPart.length(), maxmidlen);
    }
    for (String lastPart : lastParts) {
        maxlastlen = Math.max(lastPart.length(), maxlastlen);
    }
    List<Integer> hashmuls = new ArrayList<>();
    String baseStr = "\u0001";
    for (int i = 0; i <= maxmidlen + maxlastlen; i++) {
        hashmuls.add(baseStr.hashCode());
        baseStr += "\0";
    }
    // now change each hashmuls into its negative "reciprocal"
    for (int i = 0; i < hashmuls.size(); i++) {
        hashmuls.set(i, -findIntInverse(hashmuls.get(i)));
    }
    for (String lastPart : lastParts) {
        for (String midPart : midParts) {
            String tail = midPart + lastPart;
            Integer target = hashmuls.get(tail.length()) * (tail.hashCode() - targetHash);
            if (firstHashes.containsKey(target)) {
                System.out.print(firstHashes.get(target));
                System.out.println(tail);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some interesting finds found by using a list of common English words to seed each part:

```
sand nearby chair
king concentration feeling
childhood dish tight
war defensive to
ear account virus
```

Using just `Arrays.asList(" ")` as `midParts` and a large English word list for `firstParts` and `lastParts`, we find the well-known `pollinating sandboxes` as well as `revolvingly admissable`, `laccaic dephase`, `toxity fizzes`, etc.

Note that if you give `findStrings` a large list of size *N* for both `firstParts` and `lastParts` and a short fixed list for `midParts`, it runs in *O(N)* time.